# How to set multiple lines of text into a HTML Marquee?

Tags: marquee

I want to be able to have multiple lines of text in one marquee, is this possible and if so how are you able to do this?

I tried placing spaces between the items but they either just came out almost next to each other.

Any Ideas would be grateful.

Comment: Dare I ask why you're using `<marquee>` in the first place? It stopped being cool by 1999...

Comment: Marquee with multiple lines? this is not gonna be a good UX, I mean how would the user read the second row without knowing the completion of the first row?